# Sorting multidimensional arrays by individual elements in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm just going to come out and ask. I have 500 arrays[127]. I need to sort them all by the value of the very last element in descending order. How would you do this in the most efficient way possible?

```
EXAMPLE:

float arr1[] = {3,1,4,5};
float arr2[] = {1,2,5,8};
float arr3[] = {102,4,132,2};

OUTPUT:
{arr2,
arr1,
arr3}
```

Comment: what is the type or `arr1`, exacty? Could be really easy if it was `std::array` or `std::vector` or something! Or are they all 127 elements long, so that the last element is always `arrN[126]`?

Comment: Put all your arrays in a `std::vector` and use `std::sort` with a custom comparator that inspects the last element in each array.

Comment: and your "OUTPUT", is that what you need to print? or an initializer list containing the actual arrays?

Comment: @wohlstad and how does he know the size of such a raw array to test the last element? He would rather need a vector of vectors

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I meant he should look into the direction of using `std::vector` and `std::sort`. Maybe he can wrap the C arrays in a struct that will hold their length ?

Answer (score 2):

Your could create a lightweight wrapper that just stores the `begin` and `end` iterators of an array.

```cpp
#include <iterator>

template<class T>
struct span {
    template<size_t N>
    span(T (&arr)[N]) : m_begin(std::begin(arr)), m_end(std::end(arr)) {}
    
    T* begin() const { return m_begin; }
    T* end() const { return m_end; }

    T& front() const { return *m_begin; }
    T& back() const { return *std::prev(m_end); }

private:
    T* m_begin;
    T* m_end;
};
```

You could then put these lightweight wrappers in a `std::vector<span<int>>` and sort that. Note that this will not affect the original arrays in any way and since sorting the vector only moves the `span`s around and not the actual array data, it should be reasonably fast.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int arr1[] = {3,1,4,5};
    int arr2[] = {1,2,5,8};
    int arr3[] = {102,4,132,2};

    std::vector<span<int>> arrs{
        arr1, arr2, arr3
    };

    // sort on the last element, decending:
    std::sort(arrs.begin(), arrs.end(),[](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return rhs.back() < lhs.back();
    });

    for(auto& arr : arrs) {
        for(auto v : arr) std::cout << v << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 5 8 
3 1 4 5 
102 4 132 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a raw array is a pointer without size information carried out, your job isn't automatic.

Either you convert all your arrays to `std::vector<float>` so you can have the last element and then have a `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`  with a custom sort operator to test, or you create a structure that contains the raw array along with size information.

```
std::vector<float> arr1 = {3,1,4,5}
std::vector<float> arr2 = {1,2,5,8}; 
std::vector<float> arr3 = {102,4,132,2};
std::vector<std::vector<float>> arrays = {arr1,arr2,arr3};

std::sort(arrays.begin(),arrays.end(),[](const std::vector<float>& r1,const std::vector<float>& r2) -> bool
{
   if (r1[r1.size() - 1] < r2[r2.size() - 1]) return true;
   return false;
});


struct ArrAndSize { float* arr; size_t sz; };

ArrAndSize arr1 = {{3,1,4,5},4};
ArrAndSize arr2 = {{1,2,5,8},4}; 
ArrAndSize arr3 = {{102,4,132,2},4};
std::vector<ArrAndSize> arrays = {arr1,arr2,arr3};

std::sort(arrays.begin(),arrays.end(),[](const ArrAndSize& r1,const ArrAndSize& r2) -> bool
{
   if (r1.arr[r1.sz - 1] < r2.arr[r2.sz - 1]) return true;
   return false;
});
```

In both cases, check if the array has size 0.